# US, Canada and Mexico state / province / region - County - City - Zipcodes lookups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, geospatial

I am working on a Rails application, and one of the requirements is to develop a form where (in the following order):

1. The user selects a state, or province from a dropdown
2. The user will then get a list of Counties to select from
3. When selecting a county, the user will get a list of cities; OR, they can select the entire county
4. When they finish their selection, they get a list of zip codes / postal codes to select from

Doing some research, I found a gem (countries), but it's not complete, and it does not do what I want. I then found this government site: http://www.sba.gov/about-sba/sba_performance/sba_data_store/web_service_api/u_s_city_and_county_web_data_api

I now have the State, Counties and cities, but I don't have the zip codes. I can use http://zips.sourceforge.net/ and then do a lookup and construct my own DB, but that seems somewhat convoluted. Any ideas? what about Canada and Mexico?

Comment: sure that there is no webservice for that? otherwise, i would propose that you create one and earn a shit ton of money!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer and (FREE) dataset for US postal codes to cities in this answer:

[What are good ways to get all zipcodes/postal codes within a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258435/what-are-good-ways-to-get-all-zipcodes-postal-codes-within-a-city/20274059#20274059)

Don't have an answer for Canada or Mexico.

As for the SBA.gov datasets, I've found that they only return about 1/2 (~1600) of all the US counties (~3200). For example, the dataset for Alabama does not contain Barbour County. I put together a CSV file of all states/counties, with their FIPS codes and latitude/longitude centroid, derived from the US Census 2013 gazetteer for counties. Its free for anybody to use:

http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#statecounty