# What are good ways to get all zipcodes/postal codes within a city?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, postal-code

Now I know using [Geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) I can get city,state postal codes and lot other info.How can I get all postal codes / zipcodes within a city.Like this one I found [here](http://www.whitepages.com/search/FindZip?where=New+York%2C+NY).Can I get it from geocomplete or should I query it from a geoip database like [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of sources. The US Postal Service is the authority on this. Unfortunately you have to buy the database. You can get FREE list of zips in a city from USPS through an online interactive form, one city at a time!

http://mobile.usps.com/iphone/iphoneFindZip.aspx

There are other FREE services. These are based on the US Census 2010 ZCTAs. These approximate zip code boundaries for census purposes, but are not a 100% match. Maxmind does not provide a free database anymore. Geonames does. You would have to read up on how complete and accurate it is.

http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

I've worked in the past with these things.

[ADDED] To anybody interested, I made a (FREE) CSV file of approxiamately all USPS postal codes with their corresponding cities and lat/lng. As many would understand, the USPS dataset is copyrighted and the free ZCTA data from the US Census is an approximation.

I decided to use the following method to reverse build nearly the entire set. I got the US Department of Educations NCES dataset on all schools in the United States (103K schools), and figure that 99% of postal codes would have at least on school. I used the address information to build a unique set of postal codes to cities. Statistics wise, there are approxiametely 41.5K unique postal codes. My list has 43K - assuming some postal codes have multiple entries due to being in more than one city. Also note, the lat/lng is NOT an area centroid. It is simply the lat/lng of some school within the postal code. Have fun with my free dataset!

Format: State, City, ZipCode, Latitude, Longitude
http://www.opengeocode.org/download/cityzip.zip

Comment: If you want to work directly with the US Census datasets, I have some online tutorials: http://www.opengeocode.org/tutorials/USCensus.php

Answer (score 1):

*i work here boundaries-io.com*
I think this is what you need it uses US Census as repository:  US Zipcode Boundaries API:
https://boundaries-io.com

Above API shows US Boundaries(GeoJson) by zipcode,city, and state.
you should use the API programatically to handle large results.

for example:
[image: Washington,DC with all Zipcodes in boundaries]

Comment: Is this api free & open source also are there any request limits?

Comment: It seems that you are affiliated with the product mentioned in this link. Please add a disclosure into the post to make it clear, otherwise it can be considered as spam. Mentioning the company in the profile is not enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

concept name Reverse Geocoding :-

here you can get the total address along with postal code also:-

```
places.getDetails( request_details, function(results_details, status){

            // Check if the Service is OK
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {                  

                places_postal           = results_details.address_components
                places_phone            = results_details.formatted_phone_number
                places_phone_int        = results_details.international_phone_number
                places_format_address   = results_details.formatted_address
                places_google_url       = results_details.url
                places_website          = results_details.website
                places_rating           = results_details.rating

                for (var i = 0; i < places_postal.length; i++ ) {
                    if (places_postal[i].types == "postal_code" && ){
                        console.log(places_postal[i].long_name)
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

[Example directly from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?csw=1)

and for retrieving  Zip-code

```
var address = results[0].address_components;
var zipcode = address[address.length - 1].long_name;
```